# Re-writing my .HTACCESS file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know that this question has been posted multiple times on this forum.

And, i have followed every example given. Tried every code.

And, still I am unable to produce the desired result.

I'm having a problem with re-writing my  .HTACCESS file

Basically, I want to do 4 things :

(a)  remove all PHP extensions

(b)  remove all HTML extensions

(c)  remove any trailing slashes

(d)  add a bunch of "jibberish" to the end of any URLs,

so that the link is not visible to the untrained eye.

I haven't found anything online regarding how to handle that fourth issue

As for the first three, I got this from an online tutorial :

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

 # remove the .html extension
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
 RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

 # remove the .php extension
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

 # remove trailing slash if not a directory
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
 # RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

But, it's not working.

In my HTML/PHP files,  I tried to run a test by removing the extensions.

For example, I changed :

```
<"/My_folder/begin.html">  to <"/My_folder/begin">
```

I removed the HTML extension  (I did the same for PHP files, too)

I got,

> 404 errors :  "Page Not Found"

Obviously, my  `HTACCESS` file is wrong.

But, not sure what the issue is  :(

**UPDATE**

After extensive research,  this is what I have created as my  HTACCESS file :

```
 # disable directory browsing
 Options -Indexes

 # enable Multiviews
 Options -MultiViews

 # allow server to process and follow all "fictional" URLs.
 Options +FollowSymlinks

 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

But, it's still not working

**UPDATE**

I finally got it working

I simply commented out EVERY other line from the code, and left only this :

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # disable directory browsing
 Options -Indexes
 # enable Multiviews
 Options -MultiViews
 # allow server to process and follow all "fictional" URLs.
 Options +FollowSymlinks

 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

 #RewriteEngine On
 #RewriteBase /
 #RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
 #RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

For the world of me, I cannot figure out exactly WHAT was bothering the code in the first place.

Obviously,  **htaccess** can accept hundreds of lines of code.

But, how to layer them, in the proper order ?  Because, by process of elimination  (that is, by commenting out each line separately), I can conclude that my code-syntax was wrong!

But, why exactly?

Should I declare a condition (COND) before every single RULE ?

Like this :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Or...........should I declare the conditions only ONCE..........and then right all the rules below it :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

I have examined every available online tutorial, and it does not address this point anywhere.

Comment: You got 404 because it redirects to the page without extension, which doesnt exist.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  My question was : what's the issue with the htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you mentioned in the comment.. You'r htaccess **is not** properly configured.

I found a very good explained answer online. [Link here](http://strikeawe.com/blog/2009/01/extensionless-urls-with-htaccess)

> > After a number of roundabout tries, I managed to get URL rewriting working the way I wanted to so that I could make pretty extensionless
> >     URLs for my websites (e.g. domain.com/thispage).
>
> Because I personally found htaccess and mod-rewrite to be poorly
>   documented except for the painfully technical apache documentation, I
>   thought I'd break down the code I'm using:
>
> Options +FollowSymlinks First, just to be on the safe side, we make
>   sure that the FollowSymlinks option is enabled so the server will
>   actually process and follow our "fictional" URLs.
>
> RewriteEngine On RewriteEngine is the mod-rewrite worker that is going
>   to do all our work, so we have to turn it on.
>
> RewriteBase /yourdir This lets us set any directory as the base for
>   rewriting and makes it easier to write our regular expressions and
>   rewrites since we don't have to deal with pesky base directories. It's
>   also really handy when migrating the code from a directory on a
>   development server to the live site's root.
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.[^./]+)$ Since we don't want to make
>   any existing files inaccessible, we make sure that the URI (in this
>   case the part of the URL after our base directory) doesn't have a file
>   extension. The regular expression more literally checks that it "does
>   not contain a period followed by one or more characters that is not a
>   period or a slash."
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d This tells the Rewrite Engine not
>   to rewrite the URL if it matches an existing name on the server with
>   the directory flag (i.e. if it is a directory).
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f And this one, similarly, tells it
>   not to rewrite the names of existing files.
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*) yourscript.php?yourargument=$1 [PT] Finally, we have
>   the actual rewriting rule. Since what I want to do is pass variables
>   to a PHP script to load content, this is how my rule is set up. This
>   matches essentially any number or combination of characters after our
>   RewriteBase that we set earlier, and passes pieces matched inside the
>   parentheses to wherever we put our $numbered variables in our
>   rewritten URL. So the first set of parentheses goes to $1, a second
>   set would go to $2, and so on. Finally, if you want to chain the
>   output of one rewrite rule to the next you set the [PT] flag to allow
>   for passthrough of the rewritten URLs.
>
> One important note: The way the RewriteEngine works is a little funny
>   given how a human would read the code... It actually tests the
>   condition regular expression in your RewriteRule before it tests any
>   of the conditions specified above the rule by RewriteCond. So in order
>   for any of your conditions to be tested the whole thing first has to
>   find a valid match to operate on.
>
> Lastly, in case you want to copy and paste, here's the whole code
>   together, ready to be plopped into a .htaccess file and give you
>   extensionless URLs by passing variables to scripts:
>
> **For the PHP**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourdir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) yourscript.php?yourargument=$1 [PT]
```

Comment: Thanks. But, this takes care of PHP files.  What about HTML files, and Trailing Slashes ?  I tried to include all three in my code. Not just PHP.

Comment: Hmmm.......actually this doesn't take care of anything. Even the PHP files are giving the same error